# Is MSMQ obsolete?

Tags: msmq, soa

I've just been chatting with a Microsoft MVP, and he told me that MSMQ is obsolete. Is this true? What's the infrastructure for SOA then???

Comment: Which MVP were you chatting to?

Comment: Not Tony the Pony, I'm guessing

Comment: Being an MVP doesn't make you omniscient - in addition its generally awarded in a specific area of expertise. So... I think that this particular MVP needs to back up this assertions (which I for one don't believe) with references...

Comment: They may just be pushing people towards the Azure Route and Service Bus Queues, but as of today as far as I am aware it is not obsolete or deprecated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, they released a new version (4.0) with Vista, and it's an explicitly available channel in WCF, out of the box, so I'd say no.

I've built new services based on it in the last six months, and there's no official MS documentation I'm aware of that says it's going away.

If you need reliable messaging, there aren't many good options. If you're already deep in database land, Service Broker may make sense, but otherwise... MSMQ

Comment: The other benefit of MSMQ over a database is that there is in fact less overhead *and* I don't have to create a database table to just store a message. In contrast though, that's exactly what BizTalk does, in that it stores its messages in a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's obsolete at all. Do a google search for MSMQ and WCF - you'll get lots of results.

Here is a good article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF_MSMQ_Integration.aspx

Comment: While I agree that msmq isn't obsolete at all, I disagree that google search result counts validate that it isn't.  I mean I can still find 22 million search results when I "google" VB6 =)

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631349/what-is-outbound-transaction-in-layman-terms ?