# What is “Outbound Transaction” in layman terms?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq, soa

We are going to build WCF services based on SOA. During a meeting recently, client explained the new system environment. He used the word “outbound transaction”.  Due to time limitations, I could not get it clarified. Then I made some search in internet. However  it leads me to different topics.

So, my question is - what is “Outbound Transaction” in the context of “**service orientation**”? Can you give an example?

READING:

1. [What is SOA "in plain english"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026523/what-is-soa-in-plain-english)
2. [What is a "web service" in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226108/what-is-a-web-service-in-plain-english)
3. [WCF, DataPower integration - secure binding necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497929/wcf-datapower-integration-secure-binding-necessary)

Comment: I think you should ask the speaker to clarify, really, but: *personally* I start to get very worried when people start talking about transactions in the context of WCF/SOA - can get very sticky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of your project, make sure you do as @Marc suggests and follow up with the client.

But, in general terms, for asynchronous or batch type communication

- Inbound message - the flow of the message comes into YOUR system
- Outbound message - the flow of the message flows out of YOUR system.

(obviously the direction of inbound / outbound depends on the point of view of the system or esb / eai hub - system architects on the other side of the interface will see things the other way around)

The word transaction might mean many things:

1. ACID Transactions (Single phase, e.g. SQL BEGIN TRAN, or Two Phase e.g. XA/DTC)
2. Compensated / Long running transactions (usually in context of a ESB or EAI or BPEL engine)
3. The data flowing between systems contains Financial transactions (i.e. business domain context, nothing to do with XA / DTC / SQL transactions at all)

Comment: The word transaction could be misused as a word to just mean communication. I am not saying its a correct term to use in this context, but in conversations the mouth can sometimes run faster than the brain.

Answer (score 1):

Say suppose you are providing a service to a consumer say A and in some part of your service you are depending on some other service provider which is providing a service B to complete your service and give the final output to the consumer. so in this case the point of contact from service A to service B (external system) is know as outbound transaction.